# Not able to display select box as ajax response in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, quotes

I have two drop-down box one with custom taxonomy and other with it custom post under the current selected taxonomy. For that i have wrote an on-change function. i have some problem with displaying out put
it's showing output like this

```
8Associate<select class="form-control" name="upload_designation" id="upload_designation" >

<option value="">Select Designation</option><option value=""></option></select>
```

instead of

```
<select class="form-control" name="upload_designation" id="upload_designation" >

<option value="">Select Designation</option>
<option value="8">Associate</option></select>
```

i am posting my on change function here
kindly help me to figure out the problem

```
function change_desgination() {
$post_val=explode("_",$_POST['id']);
$id=$post_val[0];
$taxonomy_name=$post_val[1];


$out='<select class="form-control" name="upload_designation" id="upload_designation" >
<option value="">Select Designation</option>';

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'designation',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'domain',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $taxonomy_name
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$theid=the_ID();
$thetitle=the_title();

  $out.='<option value="'.$theid.'">'.$thetitle.'</option>';

endwhile;
  $out.='</select>';
  die($out);
 }
```

may be the problem is with the quotes. Any one please help me to find the the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $thetitle=the_title(); check $thetitle value?

Comment: @Dinesh the_title() values is comming correct its ` the_title() =Associate` and `the_ID()=8` the values are coming but not inside the <option> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with

```
$theid=the_ID();
$thetitle=the_title();
```

`the_ID()` and `the_title()` will echo the values
where as  `get_the_ID();` and `get_the_title();` will return the values as string.
so i used

```
$theid=get_the_ID();
$thetitle=get_the_title();
```

refer the links

> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48523/get-title-of-post-without-using-the-title

And

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Answer (score 0):

**checked your code i suggest you to use foreach loop instead of while as follows**

```
<?php

$out='<select class="form-control" name="upload_designation" id="upload_designation" >
<option value="">Select Designation</option>';

$array = array('one','two','three','four');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $out.='<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
  $out.='</select>';
  die($out);
?>
```

**replace your data with array shown in code**